# Prove that $f(n)=n^{2007}-n!$ is an Injective Map

Tags: functions, factorial, binomial-theorem

If $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(n)=n^{2007}-n!$

Then Prove that it is an Injective function

My try:

According to the definition of Injective function:

If $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ and if $$f(p)=f(q)$$ Then we need to Prove that $p=q$

We have:

$$p^{2007}-p!=q^{2007}-q!$$

$$p^{2007}-q^{2007}=p!-q!$$

Without loss of generality let $p \gt q$ and  $p=q+m$

We have:

$$(q+m)^{2007}-q^{2007}=q!\left((q+m)(q+m-1)(q+m-2)\cdots (q+1)-1\right)$$

By Binomial Theorem we have

$$\binom{2007}{1}q^{2006}m+\binom{2007}{2}q^{2005}m^2+\cdots+m^{2007}=q!\left((q+m)(q+m-1)\cdots (q+1)-1\right)$$

Any way to proceed here?

Comment: Prove instead the function is increasing.

Comment: @Mann it is not strictly increasing as $n!$ increases much faster than $n^{2007}$

Comment: @PeterForeman Just noticed, nevermind.

Comment: Once the function becomes negative, it will surely be injective. This happens no later than at $n=2\cdot 2007$, so if everything else fails and you have machine assistance there will only be 4014 function values to compute and look for duplicates between.